# highcharts. How to shade the area between two vertical lines?

Tags: highcharts

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  title: {
    text: 'Lines'
  },
  series: [{
      name: 'Line A',
      data: [{x: 1, y: 0}, {x: 1,y: 5}],
    }, {
      name: 'Line B',
      data: [{x: 3,y: 0}, {x: 3,y: 5}]
    },
    {
      name: 'Some line',
      data: [{x: 0,y: 2}, {x: 5,y: 2}]
    }
  ]

});
```

Example - https://jsfiddle.net/bzguv643/

I have some data (the horizontal line) and i want to shade the area between 2 vertical lines with highcharts
[image]

The result should be like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `polygon` series with pattern fill, example:

```
    series: [
            ..., {
            type: 'polygon',
            enableMouseTracking: false,
            showInLegend: false,
            color: {
                patternIndex: 0
            },
            states: {
                inactive: {
                    opacity: 1
                }
            },
            data: [
                [1, 0],
                [1, 5],
                [3, 5],
                [3, 0]
            ]
        }
    ]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5gLytrpc/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.polygon

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/pattern-fills/